# How to create a pivot table when column is sometimes NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, null, pivot

I have created a t-sql that I can use via command line that builds an HTML page off of my tables.  The problem is that I cannot set the ANSI WARNING to OFF because of the following error:

```
     Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or 
     indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query 
     notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.
```

I have not been able to traced where the NULL is coming from and it is the query that generates my pivot table.   Below is my code and some test data.

```
     DECLARE @ECR_Drugs  TABLE
       (FormID varchar(max),
       Subject_Id varchar(7),
       ExamDate varchar(max),
       Drug_name varchar(max),
       Currently_taking varchar(max),
       StartDate date,
       StartDate_Unknown varchar(max),
       EndDate varchar(max),
       EndDate_Unknown varchar(max))

     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('Enrollment_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Sep 05, 2012', 'Ethambutol', 'Yes', '2012-05-12', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'False')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('Enrollment_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Sep 05, 2012', 'Isoniazid', 'Yes', '2012-05-12', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'False')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('Enrollment_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Sep 05, 2012', 'Pyrazinamide', 'Yes', '2012-05-12', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'False')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('Enrollment_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Sep 05, 2012', 'Rifampicin', 'Yes', '2012-05-12', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'False')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('Enrollment_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Sep 05, 2012', 'Streptomycin', 'Yes', '2012-05-12', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'False')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('30Day_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Oct 04, 2012', 'Ethambutol', 'Yes', '2012-05-12', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'False')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('30Day_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Oct 04, 2012', 'Isoniazid', 'Yes', '2012-05-12', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'False')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('30Day_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Oct 04, 2012', 'Pyrazinamide', 'Yes', '2012-05-12', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'False')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('30Day_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Oct 04, 2012', 'Rifampicin', 'Yes', '2012-05-12', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'False')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('30Day_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Oct 04, 2012', 'Streptomycin', 'Yes', '2012-05-12', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'False')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('FUP_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Sep 05, 2013', 'Ethambutol', 'No', '2012-05-07', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'True')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('FUP_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Sep 05, 2013', 'Isoniazid', 'No', '2012-05-07', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'True')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('FUP_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Sep 05, 2013', 'Pyrazinamide', 'No', '2012-05-07', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'True')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('FUP_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Sep 05, 2013', 'Rifampicin', 'No', '2012-05-07', 'False', 'Jan 01, 1900', 'True')
     INSERT INTO @ECR_DRUGS VALUES('FUP_ChartReview', '42-0085', 'Sep 05, 2013', 'Streptomycin', 'No', '2012-05-07', 'False', 'Jul 09, 2012', 'False')


     SELECT
       ISNULL([sub].[Drug_Name],NULL),
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Enrollment_ChartReview] IS NOT NULL THEN Currently_taking ELSE NULL END) AS Enroll_CurrentlyTaking
     FROM
        (SELECT * 
           FROM  @ECR_Drugs
           pivot (max (StartDate) FOR FormID in ([Enrollment_ChartReview], [30Day_ChartReview], [FUP_ChartReview])) AS pvt
          ) AS [sub]
     GROUP BY
       [sub].[Drug_Name]
```

Is there a t-sql solution ?

Comment: Which null you are talking about I cannot see any nulls in the result set of this query ??

Comment: The null is in the MESSAGES (MS SQL Server Management Studio) It took more poking around but I found I need to change the query to:   MAX(CASE WHEN [Enrollment_ChartReview] IS NOT NULL THEN Currently_taking ELSE '' END) AS Enroll_CurrentlyTaking